# jQuery check if input value increases/decreases on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onchange, detection

I have an input type number

```
<input type="number" value="5" id="nmovimentos"/>
```

I want to do an especific action when the value increases or decreases (alert for a simpler example).

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var oldValue = $("#nmovimentos").val();
  $("#nmovimentos").change(function(){
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if (newValue > oldValue)
        alert("increase!");
     else
         alert("decrease!");
  });
});
```

But it doesn't work because it can't detect the oldValue var.. so any clues on how to do that? Thank you very much!

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4gskg4h/)

Comment: You could use something like https://github.com/Xaxis/jquery.eye to monitor the changes of any attribute of an element and then react how you like. In the case of jquery.eye, both the old value and new value are passed as parameters to a callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of some property every HTMLInputElement has to store previous value, for example `defaultValue`. In this case you save couple of lines of code, and make code a little cleaner and concise:

```js
$("#nmovimentos").change(function () {
    var direction = this.defaultValue < this.value
    this.defaultValue = this.value;
    if (direction) alert("increase!");
    else alert("decrease!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="5" id="nmovimentos" />
```

Comment: so `defaultValue` is always the previous value?

Comment: No, normally defaultValue is the initial value but in this case it's previous because we reassign it with `this.defaultValue = this.value;`. Not intended usage of it, but it's not used often anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really liked your code! Very clean way :)

Comment: From 9 to 10 it gives "decrease" alert if you let JS convert this.defaultValue to a number, but using parseInt() it worked correctly. `var direction= parseInt(this.defaultValue) < parseInt(this.value)`

Answer (score 3):

Update the `oldValue` in the handler

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var oldValue = $("#nmovimentos").val();
  $("#nmovimentos").change(function() {
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if (newValue > oldValue)
      console.log("increase!");
    else
      console.log("decrease!");

    oldValue = newValue;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="5" id="nmovimentos" />
```

**Or**, use a `data-*` attribute to keep track

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nmovimentos").attr('data-prev-val', $("#nmovimentos").val());
  $("#nmovimentos").change(function() {
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if (newValue > $(this).attr('data-prev-val'))
      console.log("increase!");
    else
      console.log("decrease!");

    $("#nmovimentos").attr('data-prev-val', newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="5" id="nmovimentos" />
```

Comment: I can't believe it was something so simple as frogetting to uptade the oldvalue on the end! thak you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to save the old value somewhere first. [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is handy for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var nmovimentos = $("#nmovimentos");
  var oldValue = nmovimentos.val();
  nmovimentos.data("oldValue", oldValue);
  
  $("#nmovimentos").change(function(){
    var oldValue = $(this).data("oldValue");
    var newValue = $(this).val();
    if (newValue > oldValue)
        alert("increase!");
     else
         alert("decrease!");
    $(this).data("oldValue", newValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="5" id="nmovimentos"/>
```